# Auto Post to Google + from RSS Feed Content

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds

I am using Drupal 7. I used [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module for content from the RSS. So i can get the content from RSS Feeds. Now **Feed** Content types automatically saved with RSS Feeds content. So now I want to auto Post the **Feeds** content to the twitter,linkedin and facebook.I am using [Twitter](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) module.

So i can Auto post the content using rules module to Facebook[image: So i can Auto post the content using rules module to Facebook]. 
Same Time I Can Auto Post the content using rules module to twitter.[image: Same Time I Can Auto Post the content using rules module to twitter].

Now I want to auto post the content to Google + also.I am using [Google plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/googleplus) for Google+ connect to my drupal site. After saving my new node display the google+ icon and sharing option also. Same time I want to Auto post the the new node to Google+ Page.

Comment: Please frame the question clearly, what is the issue and what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: google+ does have an api, but this module is old, and doesn't implement it.

You can't post using this module.

This link night give you some more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall